# Using a google api on behalf of a user in java on a web server

Tags: java, api, google-api, webserver, google-oauth

Does anyone here have experience with using a google api on behalf of a user in a java web application?

I've found only [one guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java) that actually had up to date information on how to create an installed app on my local machine. But it only works on my own machine. As soon as i deploy it somewhere I'm in a world of trouble. And I've only found [partial and opaque](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2) information on how programmatically access a google api on behalf of someone, on a web server. I've found deprecated repos and outdated youtube videos. All dead ends.

What I really need is someones working example, a end-to-end tutorial or something that can take me from zero stuff working on a web server to a minimal product that I can build on. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would start at [Easily access Google APIs from Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/). You will most likely need an OAuth token from the user. With this token you can use the Google APIs on behalf of the users. You can read more about this here: [Using OAuth 2.0 with the Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2). If you don't have an understanding what OAuth is, I would recommend reading [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). The *Web server applications* scenario seems to apply to what you are describing.

I can't provide you with a working example or with an end-to-end tutorial. If you have read all the documentation I referenced and you have specific questions feel free to ask them. Posting code to show what you've done and where you are stuck will help.